# Excel formula to do simple divide of 2 cells is usung a =+

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I've been sent a excel spreadsheet to replicate in SSRS and the calculations used are set out differently to anything I have ever seen. for example

```
=+E2/E3 = 100
```

This gives the same result as `=E2/E3`, so to me the + does noting?

Just want to understand why the + has been added and if it does anything? I've googled it but cant seem to find an answer.

Comment: You are correct, in Excel it does nothing.

Comment: The question says `=+E2/E3=100` gives the same result as `=E2/E3`. You were probably just using a shortcut, but just to clarify, it should give the same result as `=E2/E3=100` (i.e. compares to 100 and returns True/False).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in Excel + is equal to = at the start of a formula. 
Some people use + and not =, I have no idea why, maybe a hang up from Lotus notes. Just assume it is equal to =, if its the first operator in the formula, in fact if you just type +, excel adds the =, so you get =+

Odd i know.

Comment: I will often do it from the number keypad, as it's right there, instead of hunting for the = elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The + is the exact same as a = in Excel. People do it out of laziness, instead of using a =.